# support different screen sized ( Trouble with 4.0" 480*800 hdpi )

Tags: android, xml, screen

i'm trynig to support diffrent screen and i have a problem with normal size ( 4.0"  480*800 hdpi ) Everything shows big See picture :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlN9K.png)

(5.2" 1080*1920)  See picture :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh6Nh.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#2b2b2b"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="maa.ramplusplus.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@mipmap/info"
    android:id="@+id/infoid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@mipmap/share"
    android:id="@+id/Sharebtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPercent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="80 %"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Used RAM"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
    <com.timqi.sectorprogressview.ColorfulRingProgressView
        android:id="@+id/crpv"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        app:bgColor="#d4ffffff"
        app:fgColorEnd="#ff1e22"
        app:fgColorStart="#61429f"
        app:percent="80"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:startAngle="0"
        app:strokeWidth="21dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Inmprove Your Device's Performance And Make It Faster"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Sharebtn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Sharebtn" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="O"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#e2d81a"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Total"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Free"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Free"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Total"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Total"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Total" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Free"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="O"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#e2d81a"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make use of linear layout with weight which will auto resize the image as per screen size

Comment: put your xml file so that i can help you in layouting @fphone

Comment: ok i will did it ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this for adjusting image size

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/infoid"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7.6"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus"
            android:id="@+id/Sharebtn"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

adjust weight and weightsum as required.